# Message going behind popup

Tags: oracle-adf

So here's the case:

I have a popup structure as follows in abc.jsff page:

`<af:popup>
    <af:panelWindow>
    <af:panelGroupLayout>
    <af:region/>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </af:panelWindow>
    </af:popup>`

the `<af:region/>` refers to `xyz.jsff` and is shown whenever the popup is invoked. In this jsff page, i have a form and two command buttons `<af:commandButton>` referring to some method in backing bean. When I click on this button, some validation happens on the form in xyz.jsff and it throws a faces error message which goes behind the popup in abc.jsff page.

Comment: please post how you are creating your faces message , and post your xyz.jsff

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem caused by some bad *partialTriggers*